# Android emulator booting up with black/grey screen

Tags: azure, azure-devops, android-emulator, azure-pipelines

We have a azure devops pipeline to run the automated tests on android emulator configured on MS hosted agent. Very recently ,we are seeing that the emulator has booted up with grey screen. We confirmed that emulator has not hanged and is accepting adb commands. But nothing shows up in the screen making it very difficult to debug test failures .Does anyone has clue about the issue. Had been trying to resolve it by all possible ways.Android emulator version:
31.3.10.0.

[image: Grey Screen]

Comment: how were you able to get a screen grab of the vm which runs the tests? There are failures happening at random in my pipeline, would love to see whats happening beneath